# convert date to string in VB.net returns nothing

Tags: vb.net

The result of a date query returns me the string 20150324155327.000000+120.
I have tried to convert it using `ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")` but it returns no value.

Comment: your format string doesnt match the layout of the db string

Comment: Try to convert it into DateTime and then to format. Use DateTime.TryParse() function.

Comment: `Dim converted = ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(dtstr)` wont discard the timezone offset or ticks

Comment: thanks Maciej Los, tried that and finally I user parseExact

Comment: Plutonix, thanks for your solution, it converts the date perfectly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert into DateTime and then to string. (Code is in C#).

If you don't care about the milliseconds or time zone offset:

```
using System.Globalization;
...
string dateAsString = "20150324155327.000000+120";
dateAsString = dateAsString.Substring(0, dateAsString.IndexOf("."));
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateAsString, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

dateAsString = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

If you do car about the time zone offset:

```
using using System.Management;
...
string dateAsString = "20150324155327.000000+120";
DateTime date = ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(dateAsString);
dateAsString = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: also add "Imports System.Globalization"